# how to use grails ${createLink} in javascript

Tags: javascript, grails

i have a javascript function as follows

```
function GetSelectedItem()
{
    var e = document.getElementById("country");
    var strSel =  e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(strSel);
    var url = "${createLink(controller:'country', action: 'wholeTestUnits', id: strSel)}"
    alert(url);
 }
```

i want to go to that url action when i click the submit button like

```
<button class="submit_small" onClick="GetSelectedItem();">
    <span><g:message code="default.button.submit.label" /></span>
</button>
```

This `${createLink}` is not working.

Comment: is your url is showing in your alert or not?

Comment: Is this function on GSP page?

Answer (score 3):

A better way of doing this which doesn't require the JavaScript code be in your GSP would be the following:

```
<button class="submit_small" onClick="GetSelectedItem();" data-url="${createLink(controller:'country', action: 'wholeTestUnits')}">
    <span><g:message code="default.button.submit.label" /></span>
</button>

function GetSelectedItem() {
    var button = event.target;
    var e = document.getElementById("country");
    var strSel =  e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var url = button.getAttribute("data-url") + "/" + strSel;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a serverside/clientside problem.  The createLink is run on the server, the JS is run on the client...

Try:

```
var url = '${createLink(controller:'country', action: 'wholeTestUnits')}' + strSel ;
```

Comment: Is that function in a JS script or a GSP?  Can you quantify _'not working'_?  Just saying _"It's not working"_ doesn't really help anyone to help you...

Comment: Its a javascript function inside a gsp page

Comment: So what error do you get?  What does the generated javascript look like if you view source of the page?

Answer (score 1):

As I think , you are not getting value of strSel in your link.
You can try this.

```
function GetSelectedItem()
{
        var e = document.getElementById("country");
        var strSel =  e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        alert(strSel);
        var url = "${grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL}/country/wholeTestUnits/" + strSel
        alert(url);
}
```

Comment: You need to define that property before use it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the createLink you could build your own URL and use that one instead. You have to pay attention to capital letters in the controller name, though.

`var url="${ createLink(controller:'testcontroller', action:'getData') }";`

is equivalent to

`var url = "/testcontroller/getData;`

If you want to pass in arguments from javascript to the controller you can do like this.

```
var url = "/testcontroller/getData?arg0=" + arg0 + "&arg1=" + arg1;
```

To extract the arguments in the controller you do use the params keyword.
So to print the parameters in the controller you do this:

```
println params.arg0
println params.arg1
```

Comment: If in cookieless mode you won't get a session id added to url then.

Answer (score 0):

```
    --in gsp file--
   <a href="#" onclick="callAjax('${createLink(controller:'shift',action: 'addShift')}');" >Add/Edit Shift</a>


    --in js file--
    function callAjax(path){
    //path->/shift/addShift
       var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("updateContent").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET", path, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
var url = "${createLink(controller:'country', action: 'wholeTestUnits', params:[id: strSel], absolute: true)}"